# Adjusting img-height in a tablecell

Tags: html, css, html-table

Whenever I place an image in a table cell the image never takes up the whole cell (example below) and you can see the cell's background.
I've tried adjusting the height of the image and padding of the cell.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<td rowspan="7"><img src=. alt=. /><td>
```

Comment: img are inline-block element and stand on the baseline. A 0.2em average gap shows underneath to leve space for letters like jp or y . you can reset vertical-align to top or bottom for image or make it display:block;. Height: 100% will not really work in table-cell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
img{
    vertical-align: top; 
}

td{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hbq2wq6c/)**

You can see in demo that red background doesn't appear and image take up the whole cell.